arxiv file submission error with preamble
I am trying to submit my article on arxiv but it's not compiling. I have attached the errors which I am currently getting. Can someone help me in understanding these errors and getting rid of them. Here's what my files look like at the start:
main.tex:
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

\title{..}
\maketitle

\section{References}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}

preamble.tex:
\documentclass[
superscriptaddress,
aps]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
....

Errors: I'm getting the following 4 errors
Error 1:
*
! Emergency stop.
<*>

No pages of output.
Transcript written on preamble.log.

[verbose]: latex 'preamble.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'preamble.pre' (1723903049 >= 1723903048)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5796623/ && pdflatex 'preamble.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./preamble.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for
documentation)
ltxutil[2020/10/03 4.2e utilities package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter
web at superscript.com)]
ltxfront[2020/10/03 4.2e frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
ltxgrid[2020/10/03 4.2e page grid package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter
web at superscript.com)]
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps4-2.rtx)

Error 2:
! Emergency stop.
<*>

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on preamble.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'preamble.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'preamble.pre' (1723903052 >= 1723903051)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5796623/ && tex 'preamble.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
(./preamble.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[?

Error 3:
! Emergency stop.
l.1

No pages of output.
Transcript written on preamble.log.

[verbose]: tex 'preamble.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'preamble.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5796623/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex (./preamble.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[
?

Error 4:
! Emergency stop.
l.1

No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:


Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

arxiv seems to process your preamble.tex instead of your main.tex, perhaps as it contains the \documentclass command. I think it would be better to move the \documentclass out of the preamble.tex into the main.tex file and to add \pdfoutput=1 before it.

@UlrikeFischer , I did what you recommended. But I was not able to include \pdfoutput before \documentclass in main.tex. But I was able to process the pdf.
Unfortunately there is a new issue, I'm not able to view my references at all, all appear as ? in my preview pdf. And I see the following error in arxiv compilation
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape U/stmry/b/n' undefined
(Font) using U/stmry/m/n' instead on input line 30.
Package natbib Warning: Citation fei2022towards' on page 1 undefined on input
line 37.`

This is almost always caused by having your documentclass declaration in a file other than your main tex file. It works fine for humans to process but arXiv's AutoTeX engine looks for what the main file to process is by that command.
This will change in the future, where arXiv is moving to a more clearly defined and repeatable workflow. This is likely to be rolled out later this Autumn.
